# How can I filter a Java List based on a list attribute

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-boot, collections

hello :) I've been trying to filter a java list based on one of its attributes and its been really hard!
this is my model:

```
@Table(name="tools_table")
public class Tools implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String title;
    
    private String link;
    
    private String description;
    
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    private List<String> tags;
```

(theres also the getters, setters and constructors)

and I need to make a method that filters Tools that have, inside the list TAG, a certain tag. Basically, filtering tools by tag.

for example, if I have three tools ({name: one, tags:[cake, dogs, pink]},{name: two, tags:[cake, rabbits, blue]},{name: three, tags:[cake, horses, red]}) and I filter them by the tag CAKE, the three of them must come back. But if I filter them by the tag RED, only the third one should be returned.

I hope I explained it well :)

this is the method I'm trying to work with:

```
@GetMapping("?tag={tags}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Tools>> findByTag(@PathVariable String tags){
        List<Tools> allTools=repo.findAll();
        allTools.stream().filter(t-> t.getTags().contains(tags)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(allTools);
        
}
```

but whenever I make the request passing the desired tag, it returns me all objects, it doesn't filter them!

I appreciate anyone who tries to help <3

Comment: your problem is you are not reassigning the filtered list to the allTools variable. allTools = allTools.stream()...continue your code. filter does not modify the original list.

Comment: You are returning the unfilterd `allTools`. You should assign what you have filtered above your retun statment to a local variable and use that in your return statement, i.e `List<Tools> filterd =  allTools.stream()....`  and then use it like `return ResponseEntity.ok().body(filterd);`

Comment: Also, it looks like this is an entity from the database. You should filter there and not in the java code

Comment: @Nysand , hiii! I tried doing it like one of the answers here showed me, the same way you said, but it still doesn't work! it works like a normal get all not a filtered request

Comment: @Eritrean , hello! I tried doing it like one of the answers here showed me, the same way you said, but it still doesn't work! it works like a normal get all not a filtered request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `@GetMapping("?tag={tags}")` will get the `?tag=` param into the `@PathVariable String tags` argument? I think this will not work, you have to do plain `@GetMapping` and annotate the argument like `@RequestParam("tag") String tags`.

Moreover, as already mentioned in comments and other answers, `stream()` does not modify the collection it operates on - so you have to return the result of `allTools.stream()...collect(Collectors.toList())`.

**BUT MOST IMPORTANT OF ALL** (although only indirectly related to the question), what you are doing is fetch everything from the DB and filter in memory. **THIS WILL KILL YOUR REAL APP**, where there may be thousands of tools. Even if this specific application contains only a handful of tools, this is a bad practice and it will most certainly "bite" you in the future. Let the DB handle this operation, e.g. with a JPA query like `SELECT t FROM Tools t WHERE :tag MEMBER OF t.tags`.

Comment: thank you SO MUCH!!!!! This worked perfectly. And thank you for the tip about queries! I really didn't know that what I was doing was a bad practice. <33333

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the filtered output to a new list. Below modified code would work.

```
@GetMapping("?tag={tags}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Tools>> findByTag(@PathVariable String tags){
    List<Tools> allTools=repo.findAll();
    List<Tools> filteredTools = allTools.stream().filter(t-> t.getTags().contains(tags)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(filteredTools);
```

}

Comment: hiii @Santhosh , unfortunately it still doesn't work  it works like a normal get all not a filtered request